# Two confusing statements, which one to use and why?

Tags: javascript

I am confused about these two statements. Both are giving two different results. For simplification I am not posting full code here. The key point is I want to know the difference between the two. say, I want to invoke a function when I scroll the page. What is the difference between using a parentheses and **not** using a parentheses in this statement?

```
window.onscroll=function_Name;
```

And

```
window.onscroll=function_Name();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With parenthesis means: run the function and return the result.

Without parenthesis means: use the function itself.

So if you want to bind a function to the "onscroll" event, you do NOT want parenthesis.  For example, if your function returns "2", then

```
 window.onscroll=function_Name();
```

would be the same as

```
window.onscroll="2";
```

which wouldn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

`window.onscroll` needs to be a function. If `function_Name` is a function, then the first form would be the one you'd normally use. `function_Name()` *executes* the function, so the only way the second thing is legal is if `function_Name` *returned* a function as a result (for example, `generateScrollHandler` might be a good name for such a function-returning function). But if it returns, say, `5`, then `window.onscroll` becomes `5`, which makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 0):

The parenthesis used in "window.onscroll()" means that the function is being called by the scroll event, without the parenthesis, the script will not know that it is supposed to run the code, in stead it will try and call a variable, or it will do nothing.